# 'New' Mean in php function

Tags: php, oop, new-operator

I just learn php, but I faced with this:

```
protected function form()
{
    $form = new Form(new Post);

    $form->text('title', 'Title');
    $form->editor('body', 'Body');

    return $form;
}
```

}

just want to know, what `new` mean?... I search on php.net didn't found it.

```
$form = new Form(new Post);
```

on code above `new Form` and `new Post` what `new` mean, and its for what?...

thank you~

Comment: `Once you defined your class, then you can create as many objects as you like of that class type. Above is an example of how to create object using new operator.`

Comment: Check following link - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the "new" keyword in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219966/using-the-new-keyword-in-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

> To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used.

From Documentation Read about [new](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)

please read this thread also about using `new` [inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220212/9128487)

worth of mention so i updated.